# Error Connecting to server with SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Problem logging in with SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005?
When I try connecting to a server in SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005 with Server Name as PC-Name\MSSMLBIZ\SQLEXPRESS or ./SQLEXPRESS and Windows Authentication it shows that required instance is not found and I opened my SQL Server Configuration Manager It had just two instance or name (MSSMLBIZ and SQL Server Browser) and it had no SQLEXPRESS which may the problem why I was not able connect. How do I get my SQLEXPRESS running I want to compile my queries?? HELP !!!

Comment: Did you try `PC-Name\MSSMLBIZ`?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with :

```
.\MSSMLBIZ
```

OR

```
(local)\MSSMLBIZ
```